# View's alpha is always whether 0 or 1

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, alpha

I have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. Some views are added to the LinearLayout. On the ScrollView, a scrollListener is attached and changes the alpha of the LinearLayout while scrolling. The problem is that, until 8 Views added to the LinearLayout, it works as expected, the fading on scroll is acting exactly like I wanted it to. But 9 or more views added to the LinearLayout and its alpha becomes a trigger that becomes visible when its alpha gets to 1, and invisible when between 1 and 0. Here's my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
            android:alpha="0"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/news_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the scrolling management part :

```
if (scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        final int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                        final float alpha = (1.0f / newsTitle.getY()) * scrollY;

                        newsLayout.setAlpha(alpha > 1 ? 1 : alpha);
                        arrow.setAlpha(1 - alpha);
                        Log.e(TAG, "scrollY: " + scrollY + " alpha: " + alpha);
                    }
                });
}
```

The scroll and alpha values are the ones that are expected. Plus as I said earlier, it works fine until there are 8 items in the LinearLayout. Any help / clue would be appreciated.